# Why is this sound only displaying on chrome

Tags: javascript, audio, safari

I'm displaying a sound when paypal captures an order and it gets approved. The problem is that the sound is only getting displayed on google chrome, only on computers. Not working in safari, neither in chrome devices. But it's more strange that It once worked on safari for mac, then, when i tried again, it stopped working and now it only works in chrome.

This is my code, thanks in advance:

```
<script>
paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
      return actions.order.create({
        application_context: {
                shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING',
            },
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: '1.99'
          }
        }]
      });
    },
onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      var bleep = new Audio();
      bleep.setAttribute("src", "static/payment_success.m4a");
      bleep.currentTime=0;
      bleep.play();

some more code.....
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might check if there is some audio format supported with [Audio.canPlayType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canPlayType) and play it.

[also good lecture](http://html5doctor.com/html5-audio-the-state-of-play/)

```js
const container = document.querySelector("#container");

const audioFiles = [{
    mimeType: 'audio/opus',
    src: 'https://dl.espressif.com/dl/audio/ff-16b-2c-44100hz.opus'
  },
  {
    mimeType: 'audio/mp4',
    src: 'https://filesamples.com/samples/audio/m4a/sample1.m4a'
  },
  {
    mimeType: 'audio/wav',
    src: 'https://dl.espressif.com/dl/audio/ff-16b-2c-44100hz.wav'
  },
  {
    mimeType: 'audio/mpeg',
    src: 'https://dl.espressif.com/dl/audio/ff-16b-2c-44100hz.mp3'
  },
  {
    mimeType: 'audio/ogg',
    src: 'https://dl.espressif.com/dl/audio/ff-16b-2c-44100hz.ogg'
  },
  {
    mimeType: 'audio/aac',
    src: 'https://dl.espressif.com/dl/audio/ff-16b-2c-44100hz.aac'
  },
  {
    mimeType: 'audio/ac3',
    src: 'https://dl.espressif.com/dl/audio/ff-16b-2c-44100hz.ac3'
  },
  {
    mimeType: 'audio/aiff',
    src: 'https://dl.espressif.com/dl/audio/ff-16b-2c-44100hz.aiff'
  }
]

const map = {
  probably: 2,
  maybe: 1
}

container.addEventListener("click", async() => {
  var bleep = new Audio();

  let verifiedAudioFiles = audioFiles.map(pr => ({
    ...pr,
    canPlay: bleep.canPlayType(pr.mimeType)
  }))

  verifiedAudioFiles.sort((prev, next) => (map[next.canPlay] || 0) - (map[prev.canPlay] || 0));

  console.log(verifiedAudioFiles);

  for(let {src, mimeType} of verifiedAudioFiles) {
    try {
      bleep.setAttribute("src", src);
      bleep.currentTime = 0;
      await bleep.play();
      console.log(`playing with mime type ${mimeType}`);
      break;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      continue;
    }
  }

})
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">Press anywhere to play</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. Im noob in javascript and i'm struggling to implement this on my script. I have adapted all the audio types and ste them on the src part. But then I don't know how to continue

Comment: If you constructed similar array with possible audio formats like I did you don't have to do much to adapt code to your scenario. Just copy whats inside the event handler and change variables

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62240038/displaying-a-sound-when-alert-pops-up

Comment: This is the problem I'm having when adapting your snippet to my code.

Comment: If you could give me an answer on that post I would be grateful. Thank you!

Comment: I saw a question and you don't have to do `container.addEventListener("click", async() => {` stuff. I did it only for demonstration purposes. You can copy just content of what's inside event handler and you will be ok

Comment: What do you mean by inside event handler? I spent a lot of time trying to remove that line of code properly but the buttons dissapear, like it is not working. I have little knowledge of javascript. I would be grateful if you could be more specific :)